# Having trouble understanding recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class findFive {

    public static int count = 0;
    public static String result = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a nonnegative number");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number = input.nextInt();
        countFive(number);
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public static void countFive(int number) {
        if (number < 10) {// the base case
            if (number == 5) {
                count++;
            }
        } else { // number has two or more digits
            countFive(number / 10);
            if (number % 10 == 5) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To put it simply, I do not understand the flow of the `countFive(int number)` method. I know that if the user enters **5**, then the count will simply be equal to 1. However, my confusion comes from where the method is called again inside the method with 'countFive(number/10)'.

EDIT: I would appreciate if someone went through the flow of the code with a number like 552.

Comment: It's called from the else clause of the `countFive` method. What is it exactly that confuses you?

Comment: Take the code of the recursive routine and print it onto a sheet of paper.  Now make 10 or so copies.  On the first sheet trace through, line by line, the execution for a sample input, say `1543`.  When you get to the recursive call take your second sheet of paper and continue ... At some point you'll get to the end of the execution without making a recursive call and can start back through your pile of paper.

Comment: You could debug through the the source watching as each variable changes and how the program executes the following code.

Comment: Thanks all for the great answers. I will study them all when I get home later.

Comment: Do as @HighPerformanceMark says and trace through by hand, this is the best way to understand recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see how this works you should step through the code in your debugger, it will be much more clear when you see it in action

The method is counting how many times the digit `5` occurs in a number. For example if you pass in the number `515` the following will happen

1. 515 is greater than 10
2. Call `countFive(number/10)` which evaluates to `countFive(51)`
3. 51 is greater than 10
4. Call `countFive(number/10)` which evaluates to `countFive(5)`
5. 5 is less than 10
6. 5 equals 5
7. Increment `count`
8. Step out
9. `number%10 == 5` which evaluates to `1%10 == 5` - False
10. Step out
11. `number%10 == 5` which evaluates to `5%10 == 5` - True
12. Increment `count`

    `countFive(515)
     | 515 greater than 10
     | countFive(51)
     | |  51 greater than 10
     | |  countFive(5)
     | |  |  count++
     | |  51 mod 10 does not equal 5 
     | 515 mod 10 equals 5
     | count++`

Answer (score 1):

In recursion base case is created to avoid infinite calls to the same method. That is defined by you below.

```
if (number < 10) {// the base case
   if (number == 5) {
      count++;
   }
}
```

If this condition is satisfied, execution comes out of this method. If this isn't true, else block is executed.

```
else { // number has two or more digits
    countFive(number/10);  //This is where it is called again
    if (number%10 == 5) {
       count++;
    }
}
```

In this you have call to countFive(number/10)

Comment: So what happens when I call the countFive(number/10)? Does the method start from the beginning? I do not understand the flow.

Comment: Yes the method execution starts again but with a different parameter. Now it is number/10

Answer (score 1):

Well, the method counts the occurence of `5` in a number. For example, `5123512356` would return `3`.

You simply use recursion to remove the last digit of the number until you have reached the highest digit (`5` in the example on the left).

Once you have reached it, it will go into `number < 10` and see that it indeed is a 5. Then it will leave the method and continues with `51` (51 % 10 = 1), continues with `512`, `5123`, `51235` (`count++`) and so on until it is through with the whole number.

To clarify: `number/10` is called to reach the highest digit by removing the last digit of the original number until you cannot divide it by 10 any longer. And then the checks go through backwards.

Let's have a look at an easier example: `5050`.

1st call: `countFive(5050)`. 5050 > 10, so we call:
2nd call: `countFive(5050/10)` = `countFive(505)`. Still greater than 10
3rd call: `countFive(50)`
4th call: `countFive(5)`: `counter++`, the number is smaller than 10
now we go backwards through these three calls (the last one is finished)
3rd call: `50 % 10` = 0, `counter` stays the same
2nd call: `505 % 10` = 5, `counter++`
1st call: `5050 % 10` = 0, `counter` stays the same

Afterwards: `counter` = 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the input you proposed: 552 and follow the method.

At the beginning count is 0.

```
number        count     number < 10      number == 5       number % 10 == 5
-----------   -------   --------------   --------------    ------------------
552           0         false            false             false
55            0         false            false             true
              1
5             1         true             true              true
              2
```

And it'll return 2. Basically as you can see the method counts the number of occurrences of the digit `5` in the input.

Your base case checks if it's a digit (`< 10`) and if so checks if the digit is 5. Otherwise, it chops the right-most digit and calls the method again, as if the input was that new number. It stops once the number is left with only a single digit.